# Why the cofficients of the $j$-invariant polynomial are integers and how to compute them?

Tags: j-invariant

In the Page 333 of the book “Elliptic curves number theory and cryptogarphy” Lawrence C. Washington.

Given $\tau_i\in H$(up-half plane),and $j(\tau_i)$ is the j-invariant of the lattice $\mathbb Z_\tau+\mathbb Z$. Compute the values of $j(\tau_i)$ and then can form the polynomial $(x-j(\tau_1))(x-j(\tau_2))(x-j(\tau_3))(x-j(\tau_4))$.

My question is why $j(\tau_i)\in\mathbb C$, but the coefficiets are true integers? And, how to compute them?

Comment: That's moonshine. If someone wants to completely fill that to an answer, that will take some time. But until then just look up moonshine.

Comment: This is not moonshine.  It's just Galois theory with some complex multiplication.  The very next sentence in the book tells you why the coefficients are integers - you have a Galois-invariant product of terms.  That whole section is an explanation of how you compute the coefficients.

Comment: @S.Carnahan The Galois invariance will imply the the coefficients are rational numbers. In order to prove that they are integers, one needs to know that CM $j$-invariants are algebraic integers. This is, of course, quite standard and proven in any book that covers CM elliptic curves.

Comment: @ S. Carnahan  and @ Joe Silverman: Thanks a lot!  It is still hard for a non-mathematician to understand the computation process. Say just for a student who has background in computer science and knows how to write programs according explicitly description of the algorithms, where to find the consults for such algorithms?

Comment: If you can compute the roots $j(\tau_i)$ then the polynomial coefficients are (up to sign) the elementary symmetric functions of the roots.